# Chiral anomaly and fermion number conservation

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, neutrinos, quantum-anomalies

Chiral anomalies in QED and QCD violate fermion number conservation, since a U(1) vector symmetry corresponds to fermion number conservation. However, only the LH and RH fermion numbers are not conserved, and there exists no total fermion number violation in the Standard Model, right?

Comment: These are 4 only weakly related questions. Please ask them separately. For the questions themselves, what do you mean in 2.? The Chiral anomaly is proportional to the instanton term/Chern-Simons form of the gauge field, what would it have to do with the Higgs/fermion masses?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ask the questions separately now.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214873/2451